# C: Linked-list-iteration ending in seg fault

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I am working on a C program which reads through a text file, puts every line in a char array and stores the line in a linked-list node. The process of creating the linked-list seems to work, but when I call my function which is supposed to print the text stored in the linked list without any vowels (don't ask me why I would!), I get a segmentation fault... after printing all the text without any vowels.

LinkedList nodes look like this:

```
typedef struct linked_list_node link;

struct linked_list_node {
char* word;
link* next;
};
```

and the no-vowel function looks like this:

```
void print_no_vowels(link* lines)
{
char vowels[] = "aeiouy";
unsigned int i = 0;
unsigned int j = 0;
unsigned int check = 0;
link* first = lines;

while(first != NULL)
{
    printf("%p\n", first);
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(first->word)-1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(vowels)-1; j++)
        {
            if(first->word[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                check = 1;
            }
        }
        if(check != 1)
        {
            printf("%c", first->word[i]);
        } else {
            check = 0;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");

    first = first->next;
}
}
```

After printf-ing a lot, I have come to the conclusion that the program enters the while-loop in the print_no_vowels function again, even after the first-pointer should point to NULL. I have no idea why this happens -- in every other function where I use the same way to iterate through the linked list, the program does not enter the while loop again when first == NULL.

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

---

EDIT:

Here's the init function of the linked list.

```
link* read_file(FILE *input)
{
char line[100];
link *first = malloc(sizeof(link));
first->word = NULL;
link *curr = NULL;
while(fgets(line, 100, input) != NULL)
{
    if(first->word == NULL)
    {
        first->word = malloc(100);
        strcpy(first->word, line);
        first->next = malloc(sizeof(link));
        curr = first->next;
    }
    else
    {
        if(line != NULL)
        {
            curr->word = malloc(100);
            strcpy(curr->word, line);
            curr->next = malloc(sizeof(link));
            curr = curr->next;
        }
    }
}

return first;
}
```

Before you say so -- I know I'm a beginner at C. Any help is truely appreciated, I'm a noob :)

Comment: You can compile it with gdb (use -g option) and then run it again. That should tell you the exact line where the crash is happening..

Comment: This is no complete example, because the initialization of the linked list is not shown.

Comment: The line `if(line != NULL)` in `read_file()` is superfluous; an array name can never be a null pointer.  Just delete that condition and the braces, leaving the block of code unconditionally in the `else` clause.  You could sensibly use `strdup()` to copy the lines.  If it isn't available on your platform, it is easy to write.  You probably don't need 100 bytes each time.

Comment: In the last element of your linked list, the value of `next` should be `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash is because you don't reliably set the `next` pointer of a newly allocated `link` to NULL, but your iteration depends on it being NULL.  You also need to check that `first->word` is not NULL in `print_no_vowels()` before reading characters from it.

Also, you don't want `strlen(vowels)-1` — it leaves the y's around.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct linked_list_node link;

struct linked_list_node
{
    char *word;
    link *next;
};

static void print_no_vowels(link *lines)
{
    char vowels[] = "aeiouy";
    unsigned int i = 0;
    unsigned int j = 0;
    unsigned int check = 0;
    link *first = lines;

    while (first != NULL && first->word != NULL)
    {
        printf("%p: ", first);
        for (i = 0; i < strlen(first->word)-1; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < strlen(vowels); j++)
            {
                if (first->word[i] == vowels[j])
                {
                    check = 1;
                }
            }
            if (check != 1)
            {
                printf("%c", first->word[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                check = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");

        first = first->next;
    }
}

static link *read_file(FILE *input)
{
    char line[100];
    link *first = malloc(sizeof(link));
    first->word = NULL;
    first->next = NULL;
    link *curr = NULL;
    while (fgets(line, 100, input) != NULL)
    {
        if (first->word == NULL)
        {
            first->word = malloc(100);
            strcpy(first->word, line);
            first->next = malloc(sizeof(link));
            curr = first->next;
        }
        else
        {
            curr->word = malloc(100);
            strcpy(curr->word, line);
            curr->next = malloc(sizeof(link));
            curr = curr->next;
        }
        curr->next = NULL;
        curr->word = NULL;
    }

    return first;
}

int main(void)
{
    link *list = read_file(stdin);
    if (list != 0)
        print_no_vowels(list);
    return 0;
}
```

Running the program on its source code yields:

```
0x7fe75b4000e0: #ncld <std.h>
0x7fe75b403a80: #ncld <stdlb.h>
0x7fe75b403b00: #ncld <strng.h>
0x7fe75b403b80: 
0x7fe75b403c00: tpdf strct lnkd_lst_nd lnk;
0x7fe75b403c80: 
0x7fe75b403d00: strct lnkd_lst_nd
0x7fe75b403d80: {
0x7fe75b403e00:     chr *wrd;
0x7fe75b403e80:     lnk *nxt;
0x7fe75b403f00: };
0x7fe75b403f80: 
0x7fe75b404000: sttc vd prnt_n_vwls(lnk *lns)
0x7fe75b404080: {
0x7fe75b404100:     chr vwls[] = "";
0x7fe75b404180:     nsgnd nt  = 0;
0x7fe75b404200:     nsgnd nt j = 0;
0x7fe75b404280:     nsgnd nt chck = 0;
0x7fe75b404300:     lnk *frst = lns;
0x7fe75b404380: 
0x7fe75b404400:     whl (frst != NULL && frst->wrd != NULL)
0x7fe75b404480:     {
0x7fe75b404500:         prntf("%p: ", frst);
0x7fe75b404580:         fr ( = 0;  < strln(frst->wrd)-1; ++)
0x7fe75b404600:         {
0x7fe75b404680:             fr (j = 0; j < strln(vwls); j++)
0x7fe75b404700:             {
0x7fe75b404780:                 f (frst->wrd[] == vwls[j])
0x7fe75b404800:                 {
0x7fe75b404880:                     chck = 1;
0x7fe75b404900:                 }
0x7fe75b404980:             }
0x7fe75b404a00:             f (chck != 1)
0x7fe75b404a80:             {
0x7fe75b404b00:                 prntf("%c", frst->wrd[]);
0x7fe75b404b80:             }
0x7fe75b404c00:             ls
0x7fe75b404c80:             {
0x7fe75b404d00:                 chck = 0;
0x7fe75b404d80:             }
0x7fe75b404e00:         }
0x7fe75b404e80:         prntf("\n");
0x7fe75b404f00: 
0x7fe75b404f80:         frst = frst->nxt;
0x7fe75b405000:     }
0x7fe75b405080: }
0x7fe75b405100: 
0x7fe75b405180: sttc lnk *rd_fl(FILE *npt)
0x7fe75b405200: {
0x7fe75b405280:     chr ln[100];
0x7fe75b405300:     lnk *frst = mllc(szf(lnk));
0x7fe75b405380:     frst->wrd = NULL;
0x7fe75b405400:     frst->nxt = NULL;
0x7fe75b405480:     lnk *crr = NULL;
0x7fe75b405500:     whl (fgts(ln, 100, npt) != NULL)
0x7fe75b405580:     {
0x7fe75b405600:         f (frst->wrd == NULL)
0x7fe75b405680:         {
0x7fe75b405700:             frst->wrd = mllc(100);
0x7fe75b405780:             strcp(frst->wrd, ln);
0x7fe75b405800:             frst->nxt = mllc(szf(lnk));
0x7fe75b405880:             crr = frst->nxt;
0x7fe75b405900:         }
0x7fe75b405980:         ls
0x7fe75b405a00:         {
0x7fe75b405a80:             crr->wrd = mllc(100);
0x7fe75b405b00:             strcp(crr->wrd, ln);
0x7fe75b405b80:             crr->nxt = mllc(szf(lnk));
0x7fe75b405c00:             crr = crr->nxt;
0x7fe75b405c80:         }
0x7fe75b405d00:         crr->nxt = NULL;
0x7fe75b405d80:         crr->wrd = NULL;
0x7fe75b405e00:     }
0x7fe75b405e80: 
0x7fe75b405f00:     rtrn frst;
0x7fe75b405f80: }
0x7fe75b406000: 
0x7fe75b406080: nt mn(vd)
0x7fe75b406100: {
0x7fe75b406180:     lnk *lst = rd_fl(stdn);
0x7fe75b406200:     f (lst != 0)
0x7fe75b406280:         prnt_n_vwls(lst);
0x7fe75b406300:     rtrn 0;
0x7fe75b406380: }
```

There is still plenty of room for improvement in the code, but at least it is not crashing.  Amongst other things, you need to write the code free the list.  It should still be revised to use `strdup()`.

Comment: Thanks, that solved it for me. I will work on the code to free the list, and look up strdup(). It seems like the problem was with the first->word which was NULL in the last element of the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i = 0; i < strlen(first->word)-1; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < strlen(vowels)-1; j++)
```

You do not want to use strlen()-1 but simply strlen. An empty string from
a blank line  will underflow i to 0xFFFFFFFF (if you are running on a 32-bit architecture) and cause you to access invalid memory in word

Edit: You also need to initialize the last element of your list to NULL

```
 curr = first->next;
 curr->next = NULL;
```

and

```
curr = curr->next;
curr->next = NULL;
```

Comment: And don't use `strlen()` in the loop condition; that makes the algorithm quadratic in the length of the word because it has to calculate the length of the string each time around the loop.

Comment: Thanks, but removing the -1 does nothing but changing the output (printing the \n at the end of each line). Still getting segfault I'm afraid.
@JonathanLeffler Yeah I guess I would if I was working with longer text files, but to be honest, at least at the moment, I am not working with any n higher than 6, so it's unnoticable. Thanks for the tip anyway :)